# C# Selenium WebDriver - How to get pure text with FindElement.(By.XPath).Text

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with `FindElement(By.XPath).Text`. Result from this element is text:

> 2019-01-01 01:01:01.

Do not know how to get pure text without **"-"**, **spaces**, **":"**. The plan is to get pure text formatted to:

> 20190101010101

I've made it to `DateTime.Now` using `.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")` and it works (That's probably because it is already formatted to DateTime).

Is there any easy way to get `.Text` formatted to pure text without special characters?

Comment: The `-` *are* part of the text. `.Text` returns exactly what appear in the DOM, nothing more nothing less. If you want to change the string there are several ways, some of them suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use C# Regular expressions:

```
Regex.Replace(FindElement(By.XPath).Text, @"[\s\-:]*", "");
```

My regex above will allow you to select all **the spaces**, **-** and **:** and replace them with empty string in other words remove them from your string.